# LDAP Authentication with HTACCESS (Apache 2.4 on Windows)

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, active-directory, ldap

I am using this little PHP script *(minimized [working correctly] to demonstrate the point)* to authenticate AD user

```
define('WLU_LDAP_SERV', 'ldaps://test.domain.com:636');
define('WLU_LDAP_BASE', 'OU=Employees,OU=UsersGroups,DC=test,DC=domain,DC=com');

function ldapAuthentication($username, $password)
{
    $response = array(); 
    $err      = array();

    $filter = 'CN='.$username;
    $dnbase = $filter . ',' . WLU_LDAP_BASE;
    $fields = array("cn","mail","displayname");

    $link = @ldap_connect(WLU_LDAP_SERV);
    $bind = @ldap_bind($link, $dnbase, $password);
    $resl = @ldap_search($link, WLU_LDAP_BASE, $filter, $fields);

    if ($resl) {    
        $info = @ldap_get_entries($link, $resl); 
    }
    return $info;
}
```

I am trying to replicate the same process using .htaccess file but my authentication is failing

```
AuthType Basic
AuthBasicProvider ldap
LDAPReferrals Off
AuthLDAPBindAuthoritative off
AuthLDAPURL ldaps://test.domain.com:636/OU=Employees,OU=UsersGroups,DC=test,DC=domain,DC=com
AuthLDAPBindDN CN=someusername,OU=Employees,OU=UsersGroups,DC=test,DC=domain,DC=com
AuthName "AD authentication"
Require ldap-user
```

I get this

```
Authentication required!

This server could not verify that you are authorized to access the URL "/". You either supplied the wrong credentials (e.g., bad password), or your browser doesn't understand how to supply the credentials required.

In case you are allowed to request the document, please check your user-id and password and try again.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
Error 401
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code looks ok. Given you're using Windows, I suggest you add Quotation marks around your AuthLDAPBindDN and AuthLDAPURL.

For Require, try 'valid-user' instead of 'ldap-user'. At the end of your AuthLDAPURL you may also need the NONE flag - see a similar question here:

https://serverfault.com/questions/432844/authenticate-users-with-ldap-and-apache-2-4

Best of luck!